# 'Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' firebase auth

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Im creating a personal project and my brain is frozen from this error. Has anyone got an idea how to fix this? Its basically throwing me this: 'Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' Thanks to anyone whos got an idea for how to fix this. Written in TS.

Screenshots:
[image: console log]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is `btnLogin` defined? Please share the complete code block

Comment: edited right now

Comment: Wait until the DOM is ready before you get a reference to the button element. But since you are using Vue, why use traditional event listeners?

Comment: Could you share your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution for the people who are using firebase messaging api
if you try to send your local port you will be seeing these below errors
[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKuBe.png)

so the solution for this (firebase messaging api) atleast in react.js projects is to run your local server on https, which can be done something like this

```
($env:HTTPS = "true") -and (npm start)
```

this seemed to solve my problem you will get a privacy warning but just press advanced and proceed and your project should start in https://localhost:3000/
rather than http://localhost:3000/